# How to retrieve data from nested hash-map in good view?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a nested hash-map as

```
 HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String,Integer>> productAdded = new HashMap<>();
```

I added value as

```
    int price=12;
    String name="Apple";
    productAdded.put(1, new HashMap(){{ put(name, price); }});
```

and I am trying to retrieve it as

```
for(int i=1;i<=ProductList.productAdded.size();i++) 
{
    System.out.println(ProductList.productAdded.get(i).keySet()+"\t :$"+ProductList.productAdded.get(i).values());
}
```

Actual output

> [Large Pizza]  :$[12]

Expected output.

> Large Pizza    :$12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for each loop for iterating

```
for(Integer i :productAdded.keySet()) {
           for(String s: productAdded.get(i).keySet()) {
               System.out.println(s+"\t :$"+ProductList.productAdded.get(i).get(s));
           }
       }
```

You can also do this by using java 8 streams foreach

```
ProductList.productAdded.keySet().stream().forEach(item->{
             ProductList.productAdded.get(item).keySet().stream().forEach(inneritem->{
                 System.out.println(inneritem+"\t :$"+ProductList.productAdded.get(item).get(inneritem));
             });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `keySet()` and `values()` return collections, hence the additional braces. For your particular case, refactor to `keySet().iterator().next()` and `values().iterator().next` to achieve the desired output format.

Comment: Neither `keySet` nor `values` have a method `get`.

Answer (score 0):

Although not recommended, you can do something like this:

```
ProductList.productAdded.get(i).keySet().toString().replace("[","").replace("]","");
```

Same for the values bit.

or you can do something like this:

```
String brackets = "[\\[\\]]";
ProductList.productAdded.get(i).keySet().toString().replaceAll(brackets,"");
```